# Filter SQL query by remainder in running total

Tags: sql

The idea is to find the unpaid invoices, by subtracting the invoices from the amount owed, until the values meet.

Here's the first query, which returns the total amount owed `balanceDue`:

```sql
select 
    *,
    receivablesDue - case when payablesDue < 0 then 0 else payablesDue end balanceDue
from (
    select 
        a.acSubject, 
        isnull(round(sum(case when acAcct in ('120-00') and adDateDue < getdate() then anDebit - anCredit end), 0), 0) receivablesDue,
        isnull(round(sum(case when acAcct in ('220-00') and adDateDue < getdate() then anCredit - anDebit end), 0), 0) payablesDue
    from tHE_AcctTransItem a
    group by a.acSubject
) t1
where acSubject = 'foo'
```

First query result:

```
acSubject   receivablesDue  payablesDue   balanceDue
foo         180961.00       0.00          180961.00
```

Second query returns the invoices in descending order, with a running total `runningRevenue`:

```sql
select 
    ackey, 
    anvalue,
    SUM(anvalue) OVER(ORDER BY anvalue desc ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS runningRevenue
from the_move m
where m.acDocType in (
    '3000', 
    '3010'
) and m.acReceiver = 'foo'
order by m.adDate desc
```

Second result:

```
ackey           anvalue     runningRevenue
2330100000084   158100.00   158100.00    <---- runningRevenue lower than 180961.00 balanceDue
1930100000215   60034.52    218134.52    <---- runningRevenue NOT lower than 180961.00 balanceDue, BUT THERE IS A GAP OF 37,173.52
1830100000242   48258.19    266392.71
```

How can I show the first TWO rows? What will the where clause be, as a simple `runningRevenue < balanceDue` returns just the first row?

Comment: `where runningRevenue - anvalue < balanceDue` ?

Comment: Damn... I am so stupid. I overengineered it to use `lag` to get the previous row... This is way simpler. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You could use additional column with `between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding`, but this way is much simpler.

Comment: I agree. Please post the answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case filter should exclude value from current row in running total. The simplest way to achieve this is:

```
where runningRevenue - anvalue < balanceDue
```